# Pythonパッケージのドキュメントはどこで公開できますか？

Tags: python, sphinx

#### 環境

- Python 3.6+

#### 質問

Pythonパッケージのドキュメントを公開したいです。
候補として何がありますか？

以下のサイトは、github.ioでした。
https://qiita.com/kinpira/items/505bccacb2fba89c0ff0

kerasやrequestsモジュールはgithub.ioではなさそうなので、ほかにどんな候補があるのかを知りたいです。
https://requests-docs-ja.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
https://keras.io/ja/

#### ドキュメントの内容

- sphinxで生成したHTML
- モジュール・クラス・メソッドの説明が記載されている（API Document）

#### 公開目的・方針

- 目的：API Documentにより、どんなAPIがあるかを簡単に探せるようにするため
- 方針：簡単に公開
- 必要要件：sphinxで生成したドキュメントを公開できる

Comment: 具体的な目的、方針、必要要件などはありますか？現状、「どこでも（自分のサイト、github.io、readthedocs.ioなど）公開できる」としか答えようがないように思います。

Comment: 目的・方針・必要要件を追記しました。

Comment: readthedocs.io というサイトを知らなかったので、このようなサイトを知りたいです。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sphinxのドキュメントは静的HTMLをホスティング出来るサービスであればどこでもかまいません。
https://sphinx-users.jp/cookbook/hosting/index.html でいくつか紹介しています。
ここに載っていないサービスもいくつもりますが、[NetlifyでSphinxをホスティング](http://www.freia.jp/taka/blog/netlify-trying/index.html)する方法もあります。

Pythonパッケージのドキュメント、という意味では [Read The Docs](https://readthedocs.org/) が一般的です。
[Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/creating-documentation/) でも、Read The Docsの利用が推奨（紹介）されています。
（Python Packaging User Guide は、Pythonのパッケージ関連をとりまとめている[Python Packaging Authority](https://www.pypa.io/en/latest/)というグループが提供しているものです）